# Rally.ui.chart.CumulativeFlowChart Error

Tags: rally, code-rally

I am new to node js and rally app development. I am trying to build a custom rally cumulative flow chart. 
I am following the youtube tutorials by rally engineers. Using rally-app-builder to build the app.
My custom app throws below error on run.

```
sdk-debug.js:6582 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
loadScriptFile @ sdk-debug.js:6582
require @ sdk-debug.js:6758
syncRequire @ sdk-debug.js:6624
(anonymous) @ sdk-debug.js:2303
instantiate @ sdk-debug.js:5686
(anonymous) @ sdk-debug.js:2303
_loadCumulativeFlowChart @ App.js?_dc=0.7676518726557986:11
launch @ App.js?_dc=0.7676518726557986:5
_applyDefaultSettingsAndLaunch @ sdk-debug.js:155148
loadSettingsAndLaunch @ sdk-debug.js:155054
initComponent @ sdk-debug.js:155032
constructor @ sdk-debug.js:30211
callParent @ sdk-debug.js:4469
constructor @ sdk-debug.js:34291
callParent @ sdk-debug.js:4469
constructor @ sdk-debug.js:144823
callParent @ sdk-debug.js:4469
constructor @ sdk-debug.js:154985
constructor @ sdk-debug.js:5100
(anonymous) @ VM302:3
instantiate @ sdk-debug.js:5692
(anonymous) @ sdk-debug.js:2303
_createApp @ sdk-debug.js:225546
_launchAppInViewport @ sdk-debug.js:225453
(anonymous) @ sdk-debug.js:225410
_loadTimeboxScope @ sdk-debug.js:225541
(anonymous) @ sdk-debug.js:225409
(anonymous) @ sdk-debug.js:225308
(anonymous) @ sdk-debug.js:10091
fire @ sdk-debug.js:10046
Ext.apply.readyEvent.readyEvent.fire @ sdk-debug.js:10285
fireReadyEvent @ sdk-debug.js:10363
onDocumentReady @ sdk-debug.js:10381
fn @ sdk-debug.js:6865
onReady @ sdk-debug.js:6870
Ext.onReady @ sdk-debug.js:11162
_callOnReadyFns @ sdk-debug.js:225304
(anonymous) @ sdk-debug.js:146417
notify @ sdk-debug.js:146514
complete @ sdk-debug.js:146495
resolve @ sdk-debug.js:146359
(anonymous) @ sdk-debug.js:2260
(anonymous) @ sdk-debug.js:146417
notify @ sdk-debug.js:146514
complete @ sdk-debug.js:146495
resolve @ sdk-debug.js:146359
(anonymous) @ sdk-debug.js:146435
notify @ sdk-debug.js:146514
complete @ sdk-debug.js:146495
resolve @ sdk-debug.js:146359
(anonymous) @ sdk-debug.js:2260
(anonymous) @ sdk-debug.js:146417
notify @ sdk-debug.js:146514
complete @ sdk-debug.js:146495
resolve @ sdk-debug.js:146359
(anonymous) @ sdk-debug.js:2260
(anonymous) @ sdk-debug.js:146417
notify @ sdk-debug.js:146514
complete @ sdk-debug.js:146495
resolve @ sdk-debug.js:146359
(anonymous) @ sdk-debug.js:146423
notify @ sdk-debug.js:146514
complete @ sdk-debug.js:146495
resolve @ sdk-debug.js:146359
(anonymous) @ sdk-debug.js:146435
notify @ sdk-debug.js:146514
complete @ sdk-debug.js:146495
resolve @ sdk-debug.js:146359
(anonymous) @ sdk-debug.js:146435
notify @ sdk-debug.js:146514
complete @ sdk-debug.js:146495
resolve @ sdk-debug.js:146359
callback @ sdk-debug.js:223192
sdk-debug.js:6583 GET http://localhost:1337/Rally/ui/chart/CumulativeFlowChart.js?_dc=1512571924759 404 (Not Found)
loadScriptFile @ sdk-debug.js:6583
require @ sdk-debug.js:6758
syncRequire @ sdk-debug.js:6624
(anonymous) @ sdk-debug.js:2303
instantiate @ sdk-debug.js:5686
(anonymous) @ sdk-debug.js:2303
_loadCumulativeFlowChart @ App.js?_dc=0.7676518726557986:11
launch @ App.js?_dc=0.7676518726557986:5
_applyDefaultSettingsAndLaunch @ sdk-debug.js:155148
loadSettingsAndLaunch @ sdk-debug.js:155054
initComponent @ sdk-debug.js:155032
constructor @ sdk-debug.js:30211
callParent @ sdk-debug.js:4469
constructor @ sdk-debug.js:34291
callParent @ sdk-debug.js:4469
constructor @ sdk-debug.js:144823
callParent @ sdk-debug.js:4469
constructor @ sdk-debug.js:154985
constructor @ sdk-debug.js:5100
(anonymous) @ VM302:3
instantiate @ sdk-debug.js:5692
(anonymous) @ sdk-debug.js:2303
_createApp @ sdk-debug.js:225546
_launchAppInViewport @ sdk-debug.js:225453
(anonymous) @ sdk-debug.js:225410
_loadTimeboxScope @ sdk-debug.js:225541
(anonymous) @ sdk-debug.js:225409
(anonymous) @ sdk-debug.js:225308
(anonymous) @ sdk-debug.js:10091
fire @ sdk-debug.js:10046
Ext.apply.readyEvent.readyEvent.fire @ sdk-debug.js:10285
fireReadyEvent @ sdk-debug.js:10363
onDocumentReady @ sdk-debug.js:10381
fn @ sdk-debug.js:6865
onReady @ sdk-debug.js:6870
Ext.onReady @ sdk-debug.js:11162
_callOnReadyFns @ sdk-debug.js:225304
(anonymous) @ sdk-debug.js:146417
notify @ sdk-debug.js:146514
complete @ sdk-debug.js:146495
resolve @ sdk-debug.js:146359
(anonymous) @ sdk-debug.js:2260
(anonymous) @ sdk-debug.js:146417
notify @ sdk-debug.js:146514
complete @ sdk-debug.js:146495
resolve @ sdk-debug.js:146359
(anonymous) @ sdk-debug.js:146435
notify @ sdk-debug.js:146514
complete @ sdk-debug.js:146495
resolve @ sdk-debug.js:146359
(anonymous) @ sdk-debug.js:2260
(anonymous) @ sdk-debug.js:146417
notify @ sdk-debug.js:146514
complete @ sdk-debug.js:146495
resolve @ sdk-debug.js:146359
(anonymous) @ sdk-debug.js:2260
(anonymous) @ sdk-debug.js:146417
notify @ sdk-debug.js:146514
complete @ sdk-debug.js:146495
resolve @ sdk-debug.js:146359
(anonymous) @ sdk-debug.js:146423
notify @ sdk-debug.js:146514
complete @ sdk-debug.js:146495
resolve @ sdk-debug.js:146359
(anonymous) @ sdk-debug.js:146435
notify @ sdk-debug.js:146514
complete @ sdk-debug.js:146495
resolve @ sdk-debug.js:146359
(anonymous) @ sdk-debug.js:146435
notify @ sdk-debug.js:146514
complete @ sdk-debug.js:146495
resolve @ sdk-debug.js:146359
callback @ sdk-debug.js:223192
sdk-debug.js:147611 Error: success callback for Deferred transformed result of Deferred transformed result of Deferred threw: TypeError: c is not a constructor
    at eval (eval at getInstantiator (sdk-debug.js:5720), <anonymous>:3:8)
    at Object.instantiate (sdk-debug.js:5692)
    at Object.create (sdk-debug.js:2303)
    at constructor._loadCumulativeFlowChart (App.js?_dc=0.7676518726557986:11)
    at constructor.launch (App.js?_dc=0.7676518726557986:5)
    at constructor._applyDefaultSettingsAndLaunch (sdk-debug.js:155148)
    at constructor.loadSettingsAndLaunch (sdk-debug.js:155054)
    at constructor.initComponent (sdk-debug.js:155032)
    at constructor (sdk-debug.js:30211)
    at constructor.callParent (sdk-debug.js:4469)
```

Below is my source code

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',
    componentCls: 'app',

   launch: function () {
        this._loadCumulativeFlowChart();
    },

    _loadCumulativeFlowChart: function(){
        var endDate = Rally.util.DateTime.fromIsoString('2017-06-30T00:00:00Z');
        var startDate = Rally.util.DateTime.add(endDate, 'day', -5);
        var cumulativeFlowChart = Ext.create('Rally.ui.chart.CumulativeFlowChart', {
            storeConfig: {
                context: {
                    workspace: '/workspace/14370822888'
                },
                filters: [
                    {
                        property: '_ItemHierarchy', value: 6342428390
                    },
                    {
                        property: '_Type', value: 'HierarchicalRequirement'
                    },
                    {
                        property: 'Children', value: null
                    }
                ]
            },
            cumulativeFlowConfig: {
                timeZone: 'America/Denver',
                aggregationType: 'count',
                groupByFieldValues: ['Defined', 'In-Progress', 'Completed', 'Accepted'],
                startDate: startDate,
                endDate: endDate
            }
        });
        this.add(cumulativeFlowChart)
    }


});
```

Let me know what i am doing wrong here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That error usually happens when you're trying to create something that doesn't exist.  In this case, probably the Rally.ui.chart.CumulativeFlowChart object.  Is that a component that you have created?  Is it specified in the javascript section of your config.json before App.js?